# Parameterized include in Classic ASP with VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, include

I want to write a function that will include an external file, much like Server.Execute, but will pass along parameters. I'm aware that Server.Execute will pass along *query* parameters, but I'd like to pass data more generally. For instance:

```
' main.asp
MyInclude("external.inc", Array("mykey", "myval"))

' external.inc
Response.Write mykey
```

I doubt I can get quite that far without reading the external fine, twiddling it, and executing, but I'd like to get as close as reasonably possible. Also, if possible, I'd prefer avoiding using the query passing option for security reasons.

EDIT:

The criteria I'd like to fulfill, if possible, are:

1. Dynamic inclusion (i.e. no SSI)
2. Simple syntax to invoke (preferably a single function call)
3. Simple include files (just HTML/ASP snippets)
4. Passing as much data across as possible.

SSI fits 2, 3, and 4, and I'd use it in a heartbeat except that I don't want to hard-code explicit paths into my files. If I can use the machinery of VBScript, I can just specify the include's name and have the include function find it.

Reading a file and executing would satisfy 1, 2, and 4. 3 is violated because you couldn't put straight HTML in the include. I use this approach to import scripts because I don't need that ability, but with snippets, it's a must-have.

Server.Execute has 1, 2, and 3, but the only way (AFAICT) to pass the include data is to munge the query string. Preservation of the caller's execution context is impossible.

Writing the includes as classes would satisfy 1, 2, and 4. The include files would then be made vastly more complicated.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you are really after but it sounds like you should either put inc functionality into a COM component or create a webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function or a class in your include:-

```
'' # main.asp
<!-- #include virtual="/myincludes/external.asp" -->
<%
  External "myval"
%>

'' # external.asp
Function External(myval)
   Response.Write myval
End Function
```

For more sophisticated scenarios I tend to use a class:-

```
'' # main.asp
<!-- #include virtual="/myincludes/external.asp" -->
<%
  Dim external : Set external = CreateExternal("myval")
  ... some other code..
  external.DoStuff
%>

'' # external.asp
Class External
   Private myval

   Public Sub Init(val)
      myval = val
   End Sub

   Public Sub DoStuff()
     Response.Write myval
   End Sub    
End Class

Function CreateExternal(mval)
  Set CreateExternal = new External
  CreateExternal.Init myval
End Function
```

Comment: That fits my original question to a tee, but my motivation was to *get rid of* the SSI. +1, and question expanded to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to prove you wrong Bugeo, but a form of Dynamic/conditional include is very possible;

Have a look at WSC's Thom, they are XML based components you can code in vbscript and call from asp pages. They act as if they are COM components, but they can be edited and are interpreted on the fly like normal ASP pages.

They are not very well known in classic ASP, but they are in fact very useful and even allow you to separate presentation and business logic. A WSC can also call other WSC's, so you could program an N-tier application.

I have an example on my weblog that shows you how to call a WSC from ASP. There are also two WSC's you can download and modify. They are actually quite simple, you define the properties and methods in XML, and in the same file you can code getters and setters for those properties, aswell as all of your methods in vbscript:

http://precompiled.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/hmac-sha1-encryptie-onder-classic-asp/

Some more detailed information is here:
http://aspalliance.com/414_Windows_Scripting_Components_WSC_in_ASP

And a wizard from Microsoft to create WSC's:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=408024ed-faad-4835-8e68-773ccc951a6b&displaylang=en

Hope this helps,

Erik

Comment: WSCs are useful for including libraries, but as far as I can tell, they don't let you dump mixed HTML/ASP code – just scripts. To be honest, they look just like the import system I'm already using, except with XML line noise. The module private variables are nice, but I can fake those already.

Comment: Hi Thom, using WSC's passes all your criteria, WSC's are conditional includes. You can conditionally call them from asp unlike SSIs which are always included.
I don't know what your exact goal is, but you can instantiate a WSC object, and call it's functions or set it's properties, passing in any variable type you want. If a WSC file itself is a simple file is up for discussion, but calling it and passing in data is very simple.

Comment: The WSCs do not pass criterion 3, which specifies HTML/ASP snippets. WSCs are nice, but they simply do not contain the type of data I need to include.

Comment: Hi Thom, I'm not sure what you mean by snippets, butyou can easily do something like this:
`dim myArray : myArray = Array("mykey", "myval")  
dim includes  
set includes = GetObject("script:"&Server.MapPath("/includes.wsc"))  
    includes.WriteHeader(myArray)  
    includes.WriteMenu(myArray)  
    includes.WriteFooter(myArray)  
set myIncludes = nothing`  
 (not sure why, but the linefeeds don't work... Let me know if I should mail it to you)

Comment: @Rico in the wsc can you open and close the script tags like you can with the calling ASP? example: 'some asp code %> <p>html here</p> <% 'resume asp code

Comment: @paperreduction: No, WSCs are like COM components, so you will have to use response.write (this DOES work), or string concatenation to create HTML inside the WSC logic.  
WSC's are meant to be used as external components that can execute functions (via methods) and store data (in properties). What you describe is only needed in the presentation layer (the HTML page itself). Here is an example: http://precompiled.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/hmac-sha1-encryptie-onder-classic-asp/

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic include is not possible in classic asp.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic include is possible in ASP classic:

```
<%
 ' **** Dynamic ASP include v.2

function fixInclude(content)
   out=""   
   if instr(content,"#include ")>0 then
        response.write "Error: include directive not permitted!"
        response.end
   end if     
   content=replace(content,"<"&"%=","<"&"%response.write ")   
   pos1=instr(content,"<%")
   pos2=instr(content,"%"& ">")
   if pos1>0 then
      before= mid(content,1,pos1-1)
      before=replace(before,"""","""""")
      before=replace(before,vbcrlf,""""&vbcrlf&"response.write vbcrlf&""")
      before=vbcrlf & "response.write """ & before & """" &vbcrlf
      middle= mid(content,pos1+2,(pos2-pos1-2))
      after=mid(content,pos2+2,len(content))
      out=before & middle & fixInclude(after)
   else
      content=replace(content,"""","""""")
      content=replace(content,vbcrlf,""""&vbcrlf&"response.write vbcrlf&""")
      out=vbcrlf & "response.write """ & content &""""
   end if
   fixInclude=out
end function

Function getMappedFileAsString(byVal strFilename)
  Dim fso,td
  Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
  Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(strFilename), 1)
  getMappedFileAsString = ts.ReadAll
  ts.close  
  Set ts = nothing
  Set fso = Nothing
End Function

execute (fixInclude(getMappedFileAsString("included.asp")))
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beats me as what is considered "dynamic" when all of my includes pass variables to other includes in the page. For example on every page I use

```
<!--#include file="inc_common_functions.asp"-->
```

Then later I can use functions like getUserName(UserID) to display the User's name wherever I please.

Using a session cookie, all of the user's information can be available for logging, etc.